# R: how to reference series of df$a for each df$t starting from trigger value in df$b?

Tags: r, reference, time-series

Hard to get a coherent title on this; hope my second try here is better.
Here's a problem in referencing FAR beyond what I can figure out.  And, very sorry, I am very unsure how to generate (and can't practically extract) a useful toy example.  Fundamentally the data is annual height increments of trees, originally in wide format and melted to long, so now it's a series with all individuals repeating for each year.  It looks like:

```
Year  Tree  HtIncr  CumulativeHt
1986  1     5       5
1986  2     na      na
1986  3     7       11
...
1992  1     20      73
1992  2     15      55
...and so on
```

What I need is: per Tree, the first five HtIncrs after that Tree's CumulativeHt >= 130 (and ideally the Year that that starts as well).  So the desired output would be something like:

```
Tree  Year  HtIncr  CumulativeHt
1     1998  23      132
1     1999  19      151
...
1     2002  27      218
2     2000  18      131
...
```

Is there some mad combination of names and brackets that can grab that, or would it be better to run it through a few for-loops?  I could cook up the loops myself but I'd prefer the mad combination approach since that constitutes a description of the datapoint relations, while the loop system is just a thing that happens to the data.

Comment: Subset!  Glaringly obvious!  I've been drastically overthinking.  Thank you.  Still, if anyone can contribute the kind of solution I was imagining I'd be very interested -- it'd be a big help for getting my head around r's referencing patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
subset(df, CumulativeHt > 130, select = c(Year, Tree, HtIncr))
```

or

```
df[df$CumulativeHt > 130, c(Year, Tree, HtIncr)]
```

or

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% filter(CumulativeHt > 130)
```

Note, you can pass multiple conditions using `|`

```
filter(CumulativeHt > 130 |Year >1888)
```